# Transition function of the generalized nondeterministic finite automata

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Why does the transition function of a GNFA map from two states to a regular expression 
$$ 
\delta: (Q \setminus \{q_{start}\}) \times (Q \setminus \{q_{accept}\}) \to R $$
instead of mapping from the current state and the regular expression to the next state?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be part of a normalization for the sake of convenience.
The traditional definition would work as well.

Citing from [HanWood2004] "The Generalization of Generalized Automata:
Expression Automata"

> **Definition 2.** An expression  automaton A is  specified  by  a  tuple 
>   $(Q, \Sigma, \delta, s, f )$ , where $Q$ is a finite set of states, $\Sigma$ is an input
>   alphabet, $\delta \subseteq Q \times R_\Sigma \times Q$ is a finite set of expression transitions,
>   where $R_\Sigma$ is the set of all regular expressions over $\Sigma$, 
>   $s \in Q$ is the
>   start state and $f \in Q$ is the final state. (Note that we need only have
>   one final state.) We require that, for every pair $p$ and $q$ of states,
>   there is exactly one expression transition $(p, \alpha, q ) \in δ$ , where $\alpha$ is a regular expression over $\Sigma$ .

So this early GNFA definition starts with the traditional specification of the transition function as relation from state $p$ via regular expression $\alpha$ to state $q$.

The next paragraph in that paper is (boldface added by me):

> We can also use the functional notation $\delta : Q × Q \to R_\Sigma$ **that gives the equivalent representation**. 
>   An expression transition $( p, α, q )$
>   gives $\delta( p, q )= \alpha$ . Note that $\delta$ contains 
>   exactly $|Q|^2$
>   transitions, one transition for each pair of states, and whenever 
>   $( p,\emptyset,q )$ is in $\delta$, for some $p$ and $q$ in $Q$ , $A$ cannot move from $p$ to $q$ directly.

We note that this functional notation ($\delta$ is a function, not a relation) only allows for one expression transition from $p$ to $q$ via the regular expression $\alpha$ simply because functions are single-valued.
Thus the requirement at the end of definition 2 above can be dropped.

This convenience might explain the use of the functional notation.
To cite [Sipser2006] p. 70:

> For convenience we require that GNFAs always have a special form that meets the following conditions.
>
> - The start state has transition arrows going to every other state but    no arrows coming in form any other state.
> - There is only a single accept state, and it has arrows coming in from every other state but no arrows going to any other state.
>     Furthermore, the accept state is not the same as the start state.
> - Except for the start and accept states, one arrow goes from every state to every other state and also from each state to itself.

**References:**

[HanWood2004] Yo-Sub Han and Derick Wood. "The Generalization of Generalized Automata: Expression Automata." In: 9th International Conference on Implementation and Application of Automata, CIAA 2004, Kingston, Canada, July 22–24, 2004, Revised Selected Papers, LNCS 3317, pp. 156–166.

[Sipser2006] Michael Sipser. 2006. Introduction to the Theory of Computation (2nd ed.). International Thomson Publishing.